# Finding string text in cell using VLOOKUP

Tags: string, google-sheets, wildcard, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have a problem regarding a VLOOKUP formula in Google Sheets. When I use it in Excel or OpenOffice Calc it works like I need but it's somehow different here.

My problem is that I need to find WORD that is amongst other words in some unknown cell in a known column. For example:

```
C1 contains: "string_6 string_4 string3"
C2 contains: "string_2 string_5 string_1"
```

And I'm looking for `string_5`. All I know is that it is somewhere in column C.

How can I find this?

I was trying VLOOKUP because after finding out that C2 contains `string_5` I had to relate to D2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards in `VLOOKUP` - the asterisk will match zero or more characters and the question mark matches exactly one character.  So the following should give you what you need:

```
=VLOOKUP("*string_5*",C1:D10,2,FALSE)
```

This is the same behaviour as Excel.  For more flexibility (allows regular expressions, and can output more than one value), look at `QUERY` - detailed in [Docs help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you! That's almost it. Now what if I have "string_5" in a cell? How for example can I make it into "*A1*" ? I can't always type in what I'm looking for it must be dynamic. @aucuparia

Comment: I got it now, thank you. I used SUBSTITUTE to create formula with cell adress inbetween **.